# Given that an Object is an Array of any type how do you test that it is empty in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, types

Please help me complete my isEmpty method:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Object test){
    if (test==null){
        return true;
    }
    if (test.getClass().isArray()){
        //???
    }
    if (test instanceof String){
        String s=(String)test;
        return s=="";
    }
    if (test instanceof Collection){
        Collection c=(Collection)test;
        return c.size()==0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What code would I put int to establish that if I am dealing with an array it will return true if it's length is zero?  I want it to work no matter the type whether it is int[], Object[]. (Just so you know, I can tell you that if you put an int[] into an Object[] variable, it will throw an exception.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the helper method `getLength(Object)` from [`java.reflect.Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#getLength%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Object test){
    if (test==null){
        return true;
    }
    if (test.getClass().isArray()){
        return 0 == Array.getLength(test);
    }
    if (test instanceof String){
        String s=(String)test;
        return s.isEmpty(); // Change this!!
    }
    if (test instanceof Collection){
        Collection c=(Collection)test;
        return c.isEmpty();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that you can't use

```
boolean empty = (someString == "");
```

because that is not safe. For comparing strings, use `String.equals(String)`, or in this case, just check if the length is zero.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`java.lang.reflect.Array#getLength`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html).

Also note that your test for `String` won't work as you expect.

Comment: To elaborate, you could replace:
    return s=="";
With
    return s.length() > 0;

Answer (score 1):

A third option that builds in some null checks is Apache's [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#getLength%28java.lang.Object%29)